# get the first frame of the Mjpeg files using jmf with a client server application

Tags: sockets, rtp, jmf, rtsp-client

am  using jmf library with netbeans  8.0.2 IDE
for transporting media across network. 
so i want make a little thumbnail for the video 
founds on current path before showing the whole video 
i found a way to get the number of files with distinct file type
my files type is  `Mjpeg`  so now 
i have the files paths and names
now how to get the first frame only 
from the video and not showing the whole video 
so please Help Me!
i am using `RTP and RTSP protocols` to send packets
between the server and the client
and using the `Socket` class for building the socket